# Como hacer espacios con Emmet Abbreviation

Tags: html, css

Hace poco descubrí Emmett y es muy útil para crear etiquetas con clases, pero ¿se puede poner varias clases al crear una etiqueta con Emmett?

**Hacer algo asi pero con emmet:**

```
<p class="right bold no-divider">% Daily Value *</p>
```

Comment: [¿Esto?](https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/#id-and-class)

Comment: Gracias @Alfabravo como yo las classes las asigno asi "h1.title " ,no  sabia ese metodo.Ademas no habia pensando en la documentacion,ahora podre saber mas :)

Comment: La documentación siempre es el primer recurso a agotar hasta donde sea posible. Si se hace impenetrable o no se entiende, pues se trae como parte de la duda :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al igual que en las hojas de estilos (CSS), si un elemento tiene varias clases éstas [deben indicarse separadas por un punto (`.`)](https://docs.emmet.io/abbreviations/syntax/#id-and-class):

```
p.right.bold.no-divider{% Daily Value *}
```